# Email received but Auto Response turned on After - what does sender see?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, auto-reply

On Outlook, if I've received an email and it has been read (then marked as unread) and I have turned on auto reply after it has been received, will the sender of the email receive my auto reply? Or is it too late?

Comment: No, the auto-reply had to be turned on before the email made it to your mailbox. At this point you can choose to either respond to their email, ignore their email, or manually respond with your auto-reply.

Answer (score 0):

The key word here is "Received" ... assuming this is a server side rule (that you edit with Outlook), this means the auto-reply is sent when the message gets to the server.

You can turn off auto-reply, or set it to certain date ranges, but not decide when or if to send it per email, as it's sent from the server side.

You CAN make client side only rules - honestly, I've only used the normal type of rules, so I'm not sure when 'received' counts in that case.

If you want to send auto-reply on certain conditions, or when you do or don't want it to, I'd recommend "

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No. You may try using a Quick Step in Outlook to "auto-reply" to the message you have received.

[image]